# Could someone help me understand how did integrating both sides get to the last term in second equation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

[this image is from a book about differential equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISz9j.png)

In analogy to (9) we find that

$$
\parallel\Phi-\Psi\parallel\leqslant\int_0^z\parallel A(t)\parallel\parallel\Phi-\Psi\parallel dt\leqslant M\int_0^z\parallel\Phi-\Psi\parallel dt.
$$

From the preceding inequality one can show that $\|\Phi-\Psi\|$ must vanish identically. First we integrate both sides to obtain

$$
\int_0^z\left\|\Phi-\Psi\right\|dt\leqslant M\int_0^zdz\int_0^z\left\|\Phi-\Psi\right\|dt=M\int_0^z(z-t)\left\|\Phi-\Psi\right\|dt,
$$
so that

$$
\|\Phi-\Psi\|\leqslant M^2\int_0^z(z-t)\parallel\Phi-\Psi\parallel dt.
$$

By a second integration we find that

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best text to learn from – the double norm bars are typeset incorrectly, and the variable $z$ is overloaded as both a free variable and an integration variable.

The second equation applies [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) by integrating a factor $1$ and differentiating the inner integral. It’s not surprising that you couldn’t see this because it’s maximally obscured by the terrible choice of variables. Not only is it impossible to distinguish the two instances of $z$; they then relabel one of them as $t$ in the result. With properly named variables, this would be

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^z\|\Phi-\Psi\|\mathrm dt
&\le&
M\int_0^z\mathrm dt\int_0^t\|\Phi-\Psi\|\mathrm du
\\
&=&
M\int_0^z\mathrm dt\,1\cdot\int_0^t\|\Phi-\Psi\|\mathrm du
\\
&=&
M\left(\left[t\int_0^t\|\Phi-\Psi\|\mathrm du\right]_0^z-\int_0^z\mathrm dt\,t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^t\|\Phi-\Psi\|\mathrm du\right)
\\
&=&
M\left(z\int_0^z\|\Phi-\Psi\|\mathrm du-\int_0^z\mathrm dt\,t\|\Phi-\Psi\|\right)
\\
&=&
M\int_0^z(z-t)\|\Phi-\Psi\|\mathrm dt\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

where in the last step the two integrals were combined by relabelling $u$ as $t$ in the first one.

Comment: thanks a lot man, now it makes sense. i know that it had something to do with integration by parts, however the switch with the dummy variables had me confusing.

Comment: i decided to read this book because it is a bit advanced and i want to improve my level with mathematics, I'm looking for a book that can help me take my skills in differential equations to the next level and push me towards mastery. Do you have any recommendations?. i have a bachelor's degree in electrical engineering.

Comment: @Maran: I don't unfortunately – I haven't been learning from books for quite a while :-)